# How to compute error terms in moving average time series model?

Tags: time-series, moving-average, white-noise

Currently I am studying time series [Moving Average model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving-average_model) MA(q)
$$X_t -\mu= \epsilon_t + \theta_1\epsilon_{t-1} + \theta_2 \epsilon_{t-2} + ... + \theta_q \epsilon_q$$
where $\theta_1,...,\theta_q$ are parameters and $\epsilon_t$ is a white noise with mean $0$ and constant variance.

I have been puzzling on how to compute $\epsilon_t.$ Are they just residuals?

This [post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/26024/moving-average-model-error-terms) illustrated how to compute $\epsilon_t$ in $MA(1)$ model. But I do not see how the same technique can be carried forward to $MA(q)$ model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

" Are they just residuals?   "    . Yes !

Read my response to [Moving-average model error terms](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/26024/moving-average-model-error-terms)

Comment: In this case, what is a procedure of fitting data with MA(q) model? Which variable should we find first? As residual is the difference between true value and predicted value by forecasting model, I suppose residual is calculated the last. Since we can obtain sample acf, by theoretical formula of acf of MA(q) model, we can find variable $\theta_1,...,\theta_q.$ Am I right?

Comment: the coefficients are found by optimization i.e. trial & error through iteration.

Comment: I see. But the trial and error stage is done first? Then we proceed to estimate other parameters?

Comment: trial and error is done for all parameters simultaneously

Comment: But I thought there is a method to choose them efficiently...

Comment: no they are estimated based upon the model and the data