# Understanding error term in AR model

Tags: error, autoregressive

In AR model, the value at a time $\tau$ is modeled as linear regression of past values and an additional error term ($\epsilon_{\tau}$) at time $\tau$. In this what is the error term?

Comment: Related thread: [Understanding Moving-Average model in time series](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/442100).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An autoregression of order $p$, AR($p$), is 
$$
x_t = c + \varphi_1 x_{t-1} + \dots + \varphi_p x_{t-p} + \varepsilon_t.
$$
Its conditional mean, conditioning on information up to time $t-1$, $I_{t-1}$, is
$$
\mathbb{E}(x_t|I_{t-1}) = c + \varphi_1 x_{t-1} + \dots + \varphi_p x_{t-p}.
$$
Hence, 
$$
\varepsilon_t=x_t-\mathbb{E}(x_t|I_{t-1}).
$$ 
Therefore, one way of looking at the error term in an AR($p$) model is that it is the difference between $x_t$ and its conditional mean.

(I have replaced your time index $\tau$ with a more common $t$.)

Comment: In addition to @RICHARD HARDY , the error term is assignable to possible unspecified/omitted predictor series given the possible effect of lagged values of the output series (his X) .